# Universal Sentence Enocder for Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a large dataset having around 60M rows.I am trying to use Universal Sentence encoder to get embedding vector for text column and use it for classification.But when I am storing embedding vectors in numpy array (60M * 512) (dimension), I am getting memory error.Is there any efficient way to do that ?